# cmder starts vim in replace mode using ssh

Tags: vim, ssh, cmder

This problem is persistent with cmder on my Windows 10 PC using ssh. I also installed conemu to verify if it's just a problem with cmder. Sure enough conemu will also start vim in replace mode. No matter what Linux client I log into, when I run vim with cmder or conemu, vim starts in replace mode.

vim does not start in replace mode when I use vim on cmder before I login to a linux client via ssh, use vim with Chrome ssh client or putty or use vim on Linux machines with cmder or conemu from my Windows 8.1 PC.

Attempted to remove cmder from my Windows 10 machine including through regedit to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you use any plugins, and if yes, which plugin manager? Do you happen to [use pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/102)?

Comment: Another shot in the dark: Do you map `<Esc>` to something?

Comment: I ran into the same problem on Windows 10, tested ConEmu separately, it should be a problem with ConEmu!

Answer (score 7):

You may try un-checking these **In-console options** in *Cmder Settings > Features* :

- Inject ConEmuHk
- ANSI and xterm sequences

Save settings, then start a new Cmder console, ssh and run vim to check if the problem resolves. These features are the cause of the problem on my Windows 10 PC.

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem. Have you noticed what consequences has turning these options off?

Comment: I have both of those boxes checked, and it doesn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, for me specifically it came from trying to map something to  whilst having plugins installed. Apparently me remapping my escape ruined some sequences ran by the plugins on startup and the advice I was given was to forget about trying to use my escape key for anything, because it just wasn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if the problem is somehow related to cmder/ConEmu or exactly *why*, but I've had the problem with this configuration too (on Windows 10) and it was *definitely* related to **the Windows 10's OpenSSH client** [as mentioned in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1284561/why-is-vim-starting-in-replace-mode).

I've uninstalled the Windows SSH client and installed one from [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), and it works!

Tested with several versions from Cygwin:

- OpenSSH_6.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
- OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018